# what does the S_I prefix in S_IFMT stand for

Tags: c, posix

Here is the _s_ifmt.h header file

```
#ifndef S_IFMT
/* File type */
#define S_IFMT      0170000     /* [XSI] type of file mask */
#define S_IFIFO     0010000     /* [XSI] named pipe (fifo) */
#define S_IFCHR     0020000     /* [XSI] character special */
#define S_IFDIR     0040000     /* [XSI] directory */
#define S_IFBLK     0060000     /* [XSI] block special */
#define S_IFREG     0100000     /* [XSI] regular */
#define S_IFLNK     0120000     /* [XSI] symbolic link */
#define S_IFSOCK    0140000     /* [XSI] socket */
#if !defined(_POSIX_C_SOURCE) || defined(_DARWIN_C_SOURCE)
#define S_IFWHT     0160000     /* OBSOLETE: whiteout */
#endif
```

So what does the prefix S_I stand for exactly?

Comment: S is for stat, I is for integer :)

Comment: I think it'll be very difficult to track the origins of the `I` (and now we enter the primarily opinion-based domain). The historical reason for the `I` may be anything such as identifier, inode (where the mode is stored, but there are multiple other places where modes exist, not only on inodes... but this may have started from there [stat(), right?]), even integer is plausible (but I don't really think that it was the reason why the mind who named these symbolic constants for the first time). So basically, someone prove me wrong, as I really would like to known for sure the historical reason.